# Having troubles with a command's execution

Tags: c#, command

So, basically what I'm doing is, after adding a diagnosis on the TextBox I'm checking if there is a Diagnosis with the same name already. The connection works fine, however, I'm having difficulties with executing the command in this line here:

```
 var count = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here's the full method

```
 protected void MesmoDiagnostico_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BDClinica"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select COUNT(*) from Diagnosticos Where Diagnostico_Nome=@Diagnostico_Nome", connection);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Diagnostico_Nome", source);
        var count = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (count > 0)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Wrong command...use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead.

Comment: Hmmm ok, thanks for the info, but still, it won't let me go on, since it can't convert it to an int... :/

Comment: Since you haven't defined what "having difficulties" means, there's nothing more I can tell you.

Comment: Forget it, it was a problem with the source. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `ExecuteNonQuery` is for executing catalog or `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE` operations and returns the number of rows affected. By using a `COUNT`, you're still looking for "number of rows" but it's being executed as query, not an update.

Since you only want one piece of data, technically the first column of the first row, you can use [`ExecutScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Hmmm ok, thanks for the info, but still, it won't let me go on, since it can't convert it to an int... :/

Comment: Forget it, it was a problem with the source. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the exact code that you need :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.FrakoConnectionString);
SqlCommand maxcommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Counter) AS max FROM ppartikulieren", con);
try
{
    con.Open();
    max = (int)maxcommand.ExecuteScalar() + 1;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Fout bij het plakken:\n" + ex.Message, "Frako planner", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

you can also use a `using` statement of course. But the point is that you really need to cast the output of `ExecuteScalar`.